Specify compiled OpenSSL directory to wpa_supplicant
I am trying to compile wpa_supplicant, which requires OpenSSL, which I have compiled and installed to a custom directory, build such that the file ssl.h is in build/include/openssl/ssl.h
Now, when I compile wpa_supplicant, I get the error - fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory. The file tls_openssl.c includes it as #include <openssl/ssl.h
Now, is there a way to specify the compiled directory's header files, i.e., build/include/openssl to wpa_supplicant?
I have tried the following:-

export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/user/build/include/openssl"
make LIBS-p=/home/user/build/include/openssl

The error is still thrown.

this all sounds very questionable. On which platform are you compiling wpa_supplicant, and why? And why do you choose to use an openssl that is incompatible to what your operating system distro ships? that sounds like a chance for tears later on. Or is this a cross compile build? and why CPPFLAGS to define includes for a C program?

@MarcusMüller This is just for personal purposes. I am trying to build various programs that LFS would require, on my own. I am trying to build them individually just to have a better idea.

Ok, but that means you need to follow LFS packaging, otherwise you'll end up with conflicting versions of libraries. So, package openssl first, install it, and then build your wpa_supplicant against it.

That's exactly what I am trying to do

"installed into a custom directory" sounds like the opposite!

(1) As indicated in Light Darkmatter’s answer, I suggest that you say /home/user/build/include (without /openssl at the end).  The compiler will concatenate the specified search directory for Include files with the pathname specified in the #include directive, so it’s an error to incorporate openssl in both places.  (1a) I would also try adding a space after the -I. … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) … (2) “Light Darkmatter” asked “What are you doing exactly?” (with regard to CFLAGS and LIBS).  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  And I mean, tell us exactly what you are doing (the comments you have posted are not detailed enough).

According to the documentation (https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/android.config), add the following either to .config or to the Makefile:
# Uncomment following two lines and fix the paths if you have installed OpenSSL
# or GnuTLS in non-default location
#CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/openssl/include
#LIBS += -L/usr/local/openssl/lib

Replacing both paths with your installation directory (and removing the #).
Note: I haven't tested it.

Thanks for the reply. I had missed this in the defconfig file. Unfortunately, this makes no difference.

What are you doing exactly?

Trying to learn about these packages, kinda like LFS. I tried adding CFLAGS += and LIBS += with the full path to compiled OpenSSL, but, no luck.

The CFLAGS needs the include directory, not the compiled one. Did you add them to .config? You could also try adding them instead to the Makefile (although shouldn't be really different)
